# Where is Memcached Database store data?

Tags: caching, memcached, in-memory-database

I use Memcached DB for my website. I know Memcached is a In-mem DB, then it will cache data on RAM. I wonder which RAM does it choose? Server RAM or client RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Memchached store the data in the form of objects on the **SERVER RAM**. Memcached create a key/value pair for cached data.